# wcf restful service detail at client

Tags: wcf, rest

Is there some way that I can get list of all the WCF restful services operations at client side( something like helpEnabled).

I tried to use http://servername/service/help, but it returns complete html. I want to get the operations suported by the service in the program.
I want to list all the operations supported by the service.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: It depends on what the creator of the service you are trying to consume has exposed.

There are two sides to this particular "issue". One side states that you should be able to hit a GET endpoint and then follow links (often ATOM PUB, esp. for the REST in Practice crowd). The other is pushing WADL, a REST analog to WSDL (SOAP Services). In the first camp, there is no map and the service works more like a website. In the second, you have a description of all services.

Comment: I am not sure I would head towards WADL currently, as the trend is moving away from it. The general concensus, at least now, is you treat your REST services more like a web site.